# Compare a selenium object list with a list of strings

Tags: python, list, selenium

I am automating Twitter posting and have a list of extracted selenium objects in items_on_queue that I need to compare with a list of objects in things_to_tweet.

I need to compare these two lists and eliminate any duplicates I find to output a unique list that I can use to post.

The problem is that they're of a different format and I don't know how to normalize them to compare them.

```
items_on_queue = [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0ea37ee02c8889e324028b8a7a66568f", element="0.3932763505379022-2")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0ea37ee02c8889e324028b8a7a66568f", element="0.3932763505379022-3")>]

things_to_tweet = [('The Nanome User Story', '...', 'https://blog.matryx.ai/the-nanome-stack-user-story-530a95812484'), ('Goldman Sachs CEO sees Bitcoin as part of a financial n', '...', 'https://cryptodaily.co.uk/2017/11/goldman-sachs-ceo-sees-bitcoin-part-financial-new-world/'), ('$8,000? Goldman Sachs Analysts See Possible Bitcoin Pri', '...', 'https://www.coindesk.com/8000-goldman-sachs-analysts-see-possible-bitcoin-price-jump/')]
```

The interesting thing about the selenium oject list is that each item is in the same format as those in things_to_tweet. I only need to ad .text to the object and the result appears as such(example):

```
el = <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0ea37ee02c8889e324028b8a7a66568f", element="0.3932763505379022-2")>

el.text = ('The Nanome User Story', '...', 'https://blog.matryx.ai/the-nanome-stack-user-story-530a95812484')
```

This is the same format I have in things_to_tweet

How can I compare these two different format lists to eliminate duplicates? I guess I need to do a comparison of all el.text in a list compared with all el from the other list, but don't know how to do it.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: How do the members of each tuple correspond to the WebElement you want to compare it with?

Comment: What you call the "format" is a string representation of an object. In the case of WebElement, you see whatever the `__str__` method of the `WebElement` class outputs. This is **not** the same as the HTML element that it represents.

Comment: I am new. I am not sure I understand the question. They're both the same kind of information, a sentence, three dots and a link at the end. The only difference is that I can extract the element from things_on_queue using el.text, and I can extract the same exact text element from things_to_tweet using "el" alone. Not sure if that helps

Comment: I do not understand your previous comment. What are "both the same kind of information"? What "only difference" do you mean? What element are you extracting and how?

Comment: What are the HTML elements that you have in `items_on_queue`? How are they rendered in the browser?

Comment: It will help a lot if you give a [mcve] that illustrates how each of the variables is created.

Comment: After reading your question more closely, I have a couple of suggestions in an answer below. If neither of these are exactly what you need, I suggest that you step away from the computer and get a piece of paper and pencil. Break down the problem into steps. Describe each step **in words**. Don't worry about the exact syntax of Python or details of Selenium. Just write down **what** you want to do, not how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over both lists using `zip()`:

```
for item, tweet in zip(items_on_queue, things_to_tweet):
    if item.text == tweet:
        # do something
```

or you can loop over both lists:

```
for el in items_on_queue:
    for tweet in items_to_tweet:
        if tweet == el.text:
            # do something
```